What is the meaning of " one two many"
What is the meaning of one two many in this sentence, " Even if one person is hurt that is one two many".

You mean one too many. If a child dies of cancer, that is one [child] too many [as we would want zero dying young].

As @YosefBaskin explains in his comment, it’s not two but too.
Compare, “How many deaths is too many? Why, a single death is one more than we would willingly accept. Even a single death is one death too many.”
